# why do i need to create a database if i only have one table?

Tags: sql

For example

```
create database database_name
use database_name

create table table_name
(
pid number(3),
name varchar(50)
);
```

why it is important to create the table within the database? 
does it help in access of different table?

Comment: Why do you need a folder if you only want to store a single file? Because you can't create a file without a file system.

Comment: one could use a nosql db, key value storage, or maybe a simple text file is enough for you case

Comment: because database is kind of container which will hold your data in table format

Comment: OK. You've convinced me. Can you show me how to create your table without the database? Would be useful to know for the future. Just show me the syntax please.

Comment: A table can exist only inside a database

Comment: Store your table in a database already created, if you prefer... MySQL instalations, for instance, always come with a "Test" database. Put you table there, if you like it. But no "traditional" DBMS will allow you to create a table nowhere...

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question when you're just getting started with databases, even though the answer is evident after you got some experience in the field. Will give a +1 only to try to compensate the vast number of downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Tables don't exists out of nowhere, they always are contained within a database. The basic structure of a DB server is that it contains some DBs, then they contain in turn tables, views, stored procedures and some other objects.

Even if your entire database is as simplistic as to have a single table, it's still a database. The DB itself also adds other properties like the actual storage on disk, security permissions and lot of vendor-specific data. Backups are also made database-wide.

Also consider that in the future, your system may grow to have more than a single table, and your really want to have them grouped together in a single logical unit. It could also help when you want to have 2 instances of the system working concurrently, each one in its own DB.

Going a bit off-topic, maybe you may ask yourself why you need a table at all, if your system is really simple? Without knowing your needs, but databases might be a bit overkill for a simple list of items, so you might also think using a text file on a folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you store your data is inherently a database.  You could store comma delineated values in a text file if you wanted to, and in the most simplistic sense, that would be a database.   It's just a location to put your data.  Likewise, a table is just a way to organize data.